# Django Form not recognising model Attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

Django doesn't seem to recognise the `model` object in my custom user form.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 56, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 81, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'CustomLeiterCreationForm' object has no attribute 'model'
(venv) christian@christian-Lenovo-YOGA:~/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/rr_protokoll_tool$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 56, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 81, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'CustomLeiterCreationForm' object has no attribute 'model'
```

And this is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import Leiter


class CustomLeiterCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = Leiter
        fields = ('username', 'email')


class CustomLeiterChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm):
        model = Leiter
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

Where did I go wrong?

Edit:
The stacktrace when I had `Meta` like so: `class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/rr_protokoll_tool/tool/admin.py", line 16, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Leiter, CustomLeiterCreationForm)
  File "/home/christian/PycharmProjects/django-rr-protokoll-tool/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 124, in register
    self._registry[model] = admin_class(model, self)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: You inherit your `Meta` from `UserCreationForm`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What do you mean by that? I mainly just followed along with [this](https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/) tutorial and it's the same there.

Comment: but in your `admin.site.register(Leiter, CustomLeiterCreationForm)`, you should register the `CustomUserAdmin`, not the `CustomLeiterCreationForm`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that can't be right. I'm working in PyCharm and it doesn't even show me any import. plus, It's the same in [this](https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/) tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let your `Meta` class inherit from the `UserCreationForm`. You should not do that. You might want to inherit from the `Meta` of the `UserCreationForm`:

```
class CustomLeiterCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = Leiter
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

The same holds for the `Meta` in the `CustomLeiterChangeForm`.

Furthermore you wrote:

```
admin.site.register(Leiter, CustomLeiterCreationForm)
```

But you should not register the `CustomLeiterCreationForm` nor `CustomLeiterChangeForm`. You should make a subclass of the `UserAdmin`, and update it accordingly, like:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

```
class LeiterUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomLeiterCreationForm
    form = CustomLeiterChangeForm
    model = Leiter
    # some fields defined on Leiter
    list_display = ['email', 'username',]

admin.site.register(Leiter, LeiterUserAdmin)
```

Comment: that gave me this: ``TypeError: object() takes no parameters`` error

Comment: @ChristianGröber: perhaps, but what is the stacktrace, perhaps there is an underlying problem for that `object()`, can you edit the question with the new traceback?

Comment: I added the stacktrace